# extending default User model in Django

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-users, django-2.0

I've written my first application `Django 2.0`.

Everything is working fine and the application is almost ready when I realized to replace `id` primary key field from default `integer` type to `UUID` to make database entry more secure.

When I searched for this how to change `id` of user table to `UUID` I got many tutorials extending `AbstractBaseUser`.

Here is I have written own `User` model.

**account/models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

But I'm confused more with examples on different sources.

Every example is adding few more fields in extended model like

```
first_name
last_name
is_staff
is_admin
active
```

and functions as

```
def get_fullname(self):
def get_shortname(self):
etc.
```

I think all these fields and functions are there by default in `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

**Does extending `AbstractBaseUser` overwrites `AUTH_USER_MODEL` and it is required to add all fields which is there by default?**

also, I'm using `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` as foreign key in different models. **Should It be replaced by `account.User` model?**

I'm also using `django-allauth` plugin to enable login using the social network and use email only for authentication. **Do I require to add `email` field in the extended model with `unique=True`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django `AbstractBaseUser` provides only following fields: password, last_login, is_active. So if you are using custom User model inherited from `AbstractBaseUser` you need to define all other fields such as `email` manually.
As another part of question just adding `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'` to your settings.py file should make everything works without replace code in your project.

**UPD**
If you need field like `first_name`, `last_name`, etc. to be includet to the model you can use `AbstractUser` instead of `AbstractBaseUser`.

Comment: what if I want  to change only one field or add only one field and want rest is as default?

Comment: @AnujTBE in this case you can just extend user model. See detail here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: this will be suitable for adding new field. I want just to modify `id` field

Comment: @AnujTBE you can try to interited from `AbstractUser` not `AbstractBaseUser` model.

Comment: @AnujTBE the first one contains all required field.

Comment: If I use `AbstractBaseUser`, do I need to add `email` and `password` in the Model class?

Comment: @AnujTBE only `email` `AbstractBaseUser` does not provide this field.It has only password, last_login, is_active. Any other fields should be defined manually.

Comment: I extended the `AbstractBaseUser` but having error in login with superadmin https://stackoverflow.com/q/48070557/3719167

Answer (score 0):

As the Django documentation indicates, it's difficult to extend the User table after-the-fact, and not recommended at all for apps.  A better way is to create an auxiliary table which has a 1:1 relationship with the user-id.  Leave Django's user-table alone and just use this other table to pony-up to it.

The *"Django Annoying"* project, at https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying#autoonetoonefield,  has some very useful "juice" to make this much easier: an **AutoOneToOneField.**  Whereas Django's foreign-key field will throw an error if an record doesn't exist, this field will automagically create one on-the-fly, thereby side-stepping the entire issue.   *(The documentation page linked-to above shows exactly how this is done.)*